# PictureBox to Rectangle Collision Detection

Tags: vb.net, winforms

I am currently working on a maze game, and I have been stumped by an issue that I have tried to research, but have not found any solutions.  I am wondering if there is any way to detect collision between a PictureBox Object and a Rectangle Object?  I have already seen the methods for detecting rectangle-to-rectangle collision (Rectangle.IntersectsWith), but this doesn't quite align with my project.  I would greatly appreciate any help.  Thanks!

Comment: Use the PictureBox.Bounds for the rectangle.

Comment: ...and `Rectangle.IntersectsWith()`